# can a person take music lessons during sefirah?

Tags: music, sefirat-ha-omer

Someone who is learning a music instrument for pleasure alone, is it allowed to take music lessons during the period if sefirat haomer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Rav Nachum Rabinovitch, shlit"a, is meikil. (I believe Rav Yoshe Ber Soloveichik,z"l, was meikil regarding listening to music in general during sefira.)
Similarly, Rav Belsky [is lenient](http://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol5Issue9.pdf) with regard to continuing music lessons during sefira:

> Refer to opinions of Harav Elyashiv Shlita and Harav Korelitz Shlita quoted in Piskei Shmuos page 53, see Chut
>   Shani Shabbos 4:page 379 who permits it if one is just starting lessons since it is not music.

However, the Tzitz Eliezer (Sh"t Tzitz Eliezer 16:19), even year-round is lenient only if it is *not* for pleasure (as one part of the year-round ban *zecher l'churban* (in commemoration of the destruction of the Temple).
Furthermore, [even if it is not for pleasure and even year round](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Listening_to_Music#cite_note-28)...

> Kaf Hachayim 551:41 writes that preferably it should not be done, and even if one is lenient it should only be sad songs. Miyum Hahalacha 1:83, Emes Liyaakov 551:footnote 506 also say that it is preferable not to. The Pri Megadim Eshel Avraham 551:10 writes that parallel to the concept of davar ha'aved on chol hamoed, the rabbis permitted somebody who needs to dance or play music for livelihood to do so. )