# are you allowed get music lessons during sefirah?

Tags: halacha, minhag, music, mourning-aveilus, sefirat-ha-omer

are you allowed to start getting music lessons which he has not had beforehand during sefirah?

Comment: What about the lessons being new adds to a possible reason they might not be permitted to him?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57443/can-a-person-take-music-lessons-during-sefirah similar question.

Comment: @Laser123 Perhaps one is not allowed to start, but once he's started he's allowed to continue. The OP should edit that into his question, but I think it's a plausible sevara. I have no idea if it's an accurate one, but I hear the tzad.

Comment: it just sounds like an assumption if there is no reason to think it is different. giving an example of something during sefira that isn't permitted unless one did this action prior to the start would help this question

Comment: i am the one that posted the question and i heard that the only reason why you are allowed to get music lessons during sefirah is because your skills might ware off but if you start in the middle of sefirah there might be a problem since you do not have any skills that you will lose

Comment: @DavidKenner Dupe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rav Heinemann told us:

> If you are practicing for your parnasa or are practicing because you
>   want to have the choice to enter such a field, then that would be the
>   equivalent of practicing accounting when you’re unsure if you want to
>   be an accountant. The Shulchan Aruch (560:3) says you cannot listen to
>   music “לְשַׂמֵּחַ בָּהֶם’, but to learn a profession isn’t a form a
>   שמחה.

It would seem if you are would like to have the potential to enter the field of music for a job and would therefore require getting music lessons, you could start during sefira - just as it would be permitted to begin studying for accounting or dental school during the sefira.